# Where to place the code for retrieving filtered data?

Tags: laravel

> I need to implement functionality to search booking slot availability
>   by location, service, provider, and various combinations of these.

These will require a few queries and a lot of if / else conditions

Where should this code go?

1. **Model**
2. **Classes Interface and Implementation**

   1. Should there be a single or multiple implementations
   2. Is it helpful to use service provider in this case?
3. **Repositories**

Also, various controllers' methods will be dependant on this availability result.

Please suggest me the best way to handle this? Any details or a roadmap will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A repository is the best place to write your DB interaction code but if you are having the same filters on multiple models or repositories you can make one base repo and use it in your own repository. that's your first solution.

second thing, you can make a class for advanced queries. that is shown in the below-mentioned link you can check, it's also a good way to make your code clear and simple.

https://m.dotdev.co/writing-advanced-eloquent-search-query-filters-de8b6c2598db